# "Void" type not allowed here -- I'm new with coding

Tags: java, void

For the `public void mailingLabel()` method, I keep getting an error that tells me void isn't allowed. When I changed it to a String and modified the code to include  return statement it worked fine. What is wrong?

```
public class StreetAddress {

    private String myStreet;
    private String myCity;
    private String myState;
    private String myZIP;

    public StreetAddress(String street, String city, String state, String zip) {
        myStreet = street;
        myCity = city;
        myState = state;
        myZIP = zip;
    }

    public void mailingLabel() {
        System.out.println(getStreet());
        String p = getCity() + ", " + getState() + " " + getZIP();
        System.out.println(p);
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return myStreet;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return myCity;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return myState;
    }

    public String getZIP() {
        return myZIP;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        myStreet = street;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        myCity = city;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        myState = state;
    }

    public void setZIP(String zip) {
        myZIP = zip;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call this method? Please show the actual and complete error message, and any code that uses this class. I think that you may be leaving out pertinent information, making it harder to help you.

Comment: The code you are showing is perfectly fine.  At least, from a compiler's point of view.  It won't fire the error message you are citing.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have posted.  You need to tell us what the "it" is in which you are getting an error.

Answer (score 3):

I have to guess as your question seems incomplete, but having said that, my guess is that you're trying to pass the `mailingLabel()` method call into a println method, and this can't be done:

```
StreetAddress someAddress = new StreetAddress(...);
System.out.println(someAddress.mailingLabel());
```

The compiler will complain that you're trying to print a void, which makes sense.  Instead, either have the method return a String, or leave the method unchanged and just call it by itself and not in a println. i.e.,

```
StreetAddress someAddress = new StreetAddress(...);
someAddress.mailingLabel();
```

As an aside, consider giving the StreetAddress a `public String toString()` method override that returns a String with pertinent data that describes the state of the object.

Comment: Yep this was the problem. I'm taking the AP computer science course using the eIMACS online textbook. The "test cases" given all use System.out.println in the main method, which is why I had to use a String instead of a void. The strange thing is that eIMACS requested that a void be used in the method -- In other words, it was a problem with the textbook.

Comment: @golferguy: Before judging that the textbook is in error, post the actual assignment requirements in full. It still may be your interpretation of the requirements that are at fault.

Comment: Use the following methods:
-- other void methods ... --
String mailingLabel();. I should have read more carefully

Comment: When I submitted my code, I got this:Submitted Thursday, October 9, 2014 4:09pm, your score 8 / 10 
Your mailingLabel method does not work correctly
Your mailingLabel method does not work correctly
Your mailingLabel method does not work correctly
Your mailingLabel method does not work correctly
Your mailingLabel method does not work correctly
Your mailingLabel method does not work correctly
Your mailingLabel method does not work correctly .. etc.